# Where is the HTTP post interface to overpass.eu

Tags: overpass-api

I want to make a call directly to overpass from within my java program and then parse the returned XML (so I can subsequently populate a DB with stations)
Where is the api for http://overpass-turbo.eu/, 
i.e I wish to post a query to overpass-turbo. All I seem to be able to do is manually run a query and then select export.

Answer (score 0):

http://overpass-api.de/command_line.html expalins that it is at http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?

there doesnt appear to be an interface for the QL but I can get what I want out of that.
*edit* actually the doco is misleading, you can just post the QL at it.

If you vote down a perfectly valid question do you lose cred ?